# dotnet test command logger only writes outputs of the last test when solution with multiple projects is specified to be tested

Tags: testing, logging, mstest, solution, dotnet-test

While trying to automate my MSTest based tests using dotnet test command I am experiencing an issue where only the outputs of the last test project run (in the solution) are written to the specified logger output

I have tried running the command line is as follows :

```
dotnet test $ProjectSln --results-directory ./Reports -l "trx;LogFileName=$($ReportFile)" "/p:GeneratePackageOnBuild=False;Configuration=Release;Platform=Any CPU;SolutionDir=${RootDir}"# "-verbosity:minimal"
```

but that produces an xml file containing only outputs of a single project tests.

Is there any way to make the command log outputs of all tests to a single file?

Answer (score 2):

Since the command executes tests in multiple projects, use the `LogFilePrefix` argument instead of `LogFileName`:

```
dotnet test $ProjectSln --results-directory ./Reports -l "trx;LogFilePrefix=$($ReportFile)" "/p:GeneratePackageOnBuild=False;Configuration=Release;Platform=Any CPU;SolutionDir=${RootDir}"
#                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here is the same command formatted on multiple lines if that is easier to read:

```
dotnet test $ProjectSln `
            --results-directory ./Reports `
            -l "trx;LogFilePrefix=$($ReportFile)" `
            "/p:GeneratePackageOnBuild=False;Configuration=Release;Platform=Any CPU;SolutionDir=${RootDir}"
```

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test#examples) has a number of examples you can reference.

Comment: Thanks Greg, this is significant an improvement as it allows me to have a log file per test project. It would be even better if I could use test project names as a prefix to each log file , but it does not look like it is possible ?